# Two lightning components do not work simultaneously

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, form

I have created 2 lightning components as dynamic picklists of objects. If I include them separately to the form both works fine. But I need to use them both on one form, when I do so, I get an error that the second controller method can't is found.

**The error message:**

> Error during init [Unable to find 'getTrailers' on 'compound://c.PicklistTrailers'.]

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="PicklistController">
<aura:attribute name="trailerList" type="Object[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleInit}"/>
<div>
<h2>Trailer:</h2>
    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="trailer">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.trailerList}" var="trailerItem">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!trailerItem.Name}" label="{!trailerItem.Summary}" />

        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>
</div>
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
    public with sharing class PicklistController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Truck__c> getTrucks() {
        return [
            SELECT Name, Make__c, Model__c, Licence_plate__c
            FROM Truck__c
            Order by Name
        ];
    }
   @AuraEnabled
     public static List<Trailer__c> getTrailers() {
        return [
            SELECT Name, Make__c, Model__c, Licence_plate__c
            FROM Trailer__c
            Order by Name
        ];
    }
}
```

**js controller:**

```
({
handleInit : function(component, event, helper) {
var genTrailers = component.get("c.getTrailers");
    genTrailers.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var trailerArray = a.getReturnValue();  // Array<Object>

        var trailerOptions = [];

        trailerArray.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
          var trailerOption = new Object();
           var Summary="";
          trailerOption.Name = element.Name;
          Summary += (element.Make__c+" ");
          Summary += (element.Model__c+" ");
          Summary += element.Licence_Plate__c;
          trailerOption.Summary = Summary;

        trailerOptions.push(trailerOption);

       // console.log(trailerOption);

        });
        component.set("v.trailerList",trailerOptions);   
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(genTrailers);
}
```

They both similar the only difference is object names.

Thank you.

Comment: So you have an issue with components and you don't show the markup. Also, you have a known error and you do not say which line the error is on.... Please read [Ask]

Comment: It doesn't show a line number. The erro message is Error during init [Unable to find 'getTrailers' on 'compound://c.PicklistTrailers'.]

Comment: You say you have two, are they part of a larger component or app?

Comment: Yes,they are supposed to be on a form and if I insert only one it works.

Comment: Define "Form" Many times it is all about how things are put together. Just to confirm BOTH work when put on the "Form" without the other? It may be best to post the parent component as well....Not saying I will have an answer just trying to help you for the question so you will get one. As it stands I don't see anything that stands out as an issue.

Comment: I solved it,but you give me a great idea to check form.  The issue was in using wrong slds class. Thank you.